# Need help in postgreSQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables, `table1` and `table2`. I have written the query with some condition as follows

```
Select t2.employee_id,
t2.adddate,
t2.previousaleave
from table2 as t2, table1 as t1
WHERE t1.enddate IS NULL
  OR t1.enddate>t2.adddate
  AND t2.adddate<=now()
  AND t2.leavetype='annualleave'
```

If i run this,the conditions are not working.It is selecting all the empids of the table t2.?I checked that the problem is with the `t1.enddate is NULL` condition. Since the `enddate` column can be either,

- some date
- or, `null`

I need to get the empid if the `t1.enddate IS NULL` and the other conditions succeed. Here leave type is distinct with in each empid. (Each employee have only one row for the annualleave). Is there any other alternative way to do this.

Comment: http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/a/2642/2639

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always need parentheses if using OR

For example:

```
Select t2.employee_id,t2.adddate,t2.previousaleave 
from table2 as t2
Inner join table1 as t1 ON ............. ?????
WHERE (t1.enddate IS NULL OR t1.enddate>t2.adddate AND t2.adddate<=now())
AND t2.leavetype='annualleave'
```

BUT ALSO NOTE you don't appear to have joined the tables. Always use explicit ANSI join syntax to avoid creating an accidental Cartesian product of the rows from the tables.

If empid exists in both tables try

```
Select t2.employee_id,t2.adddate,t2.previousaleave 
from table2 as t2
Inner join table1 as t1 ON t2.empid = t1.empid
WHERE (t1.enddate IS NULL OR t1.enddate>t2.adddate AND t2.adddate<=now())
AND t2.leavetype='annualleave'
```

Comment: Thanks.I used like you have adviced. But now even if the t1.enddate  is not null and t1.enddate<t2.adddate,it is still showing me the empid.And if t1.enddate is not null and t1.enddate>t2.adddate,the empid is duplicated in two rows.Thanks

Comment: The empid is duplicated because you have not joined the tables. Whate you have done is MULTIPLIED the rows.  Does a column for empid exist in both tables?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t2.employee_id, t2.adddate, t2.previousaleave
FROM table2 AS t2
INNER JOIN table1 as t1
  ON (
     ( t1.enddate IS NULL OR t1.enddate > t2.adddate )
     AND t2.adddate <= now()
     AND t2.leavetype = 'annualleave'
   )
```

Is it possible for `t2.adddate` to be `> now()`? That seems awkward.

Comment: Thanks.I used like you have adviced. But now even if the t1.enddate is not null and t1.enddate<t2.adddate,it is still showing me the empid.And if t1.enddate is not null and t1.enddate>t2.adddate,the empid is duplicated in two rows.Thanks